# JPA-Repository read access commits outer transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have a strange behaviour of Springs DB-Transaction handling I fail to wrap my head around.

Given the following code:

```
    @Transactional
    public void saveDocumentToDB() {

        dbService.addNewEntity('123', 'helloWorld');
        DbEntity dbEntity = dbService.getEntityByID('someId');

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

Where `dbService` is some `@Service`-class with access to a JPA-`CrudRepository`.

My Problem: the `getEntityByID`-Method which in turn calls a method on the auto-generated repository-object commits the transaction and thus writes the first 'add'-call to the Database.

Without this call, the transaction is rolled back nicely...

Do you have any advice how to make the auto-generated CRUD-Methods respect the transaction as well?

Answer (score 0):

In my application.properties, I used

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

which results in Hibernate generating its tables with MyISAM-Engine, which does not support transactions (and foreign-keys).

I changed it to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

and rebuilt the db-schema.

I find it quite unintuitive, that the alleged default "MySQL5Dialect" does not use the default Engine but MyISAM.

Maybe it helps someone in the future.